# Laravel Yajra Datatable wrong search result

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am stuck to getting correct search result. Initially result is correct but when I am trying to search then it stuck only one value.

here is my code, please guide and help.

```
                    $model
                        ->where('is_back_order', true)
                        ->whereHas('products', function ($q){
                            $q->where('order_products.is_back_order_product', '=' , true)->where('order_products.arrival_status', '=', 'awaiting_for_arrival');
                        })
                        ->join('presta_status', function($join) use ($presta_filters) {
                            $join->on('orders.store_id', '=', 'presta_status.store_id')
                                ->on('orders.status', '=', 'presta_status.status_code')
                                ->whereNotIn('presta_status.status', $presta_filters);
                        });
```

under this query I am not getting correct result while searching.
Here is the full code.
https://gist.github.com/mumer44/0359a47591e7d0f514267ac74a89ebf9

Comment: We need more context to help you. Please post more code. Especially the filterColumn(), editColumn() and the getQuery() part.

Comment: Please check the full code on.
https://gist.github.com/mumer44/0359a47591e7d0f514267ac74a89ebf9

Comment: What search are you doing ? Which keyword ?

Comment: order_reference_link column

Comment: And you are absolutely sure it should gives you multiple rows ?

Answer (score 0):

## try this code:

```
$model
->join('presta_status', function($join) use ($presta_filters) {
        $join->on('orders.store_id', '=', 'presta_status.store_id')
        ->on('orders.status', '=', 'presta_status.status_code');
   });
->whereNotIn('presta_status.status', $presta_filters)
->where('is_back_order', true)
    ->whereHas('products', function ($q){
        $q->where('order_products.is_back_order_product', '=' , true)
          ->where('order_products.arrival_status', '=', 'awaiting_for_arrival');
    })
```